# Creating matching MIME Attachment with Python

Tags: python, email

I found this snippet in the official [examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html)

```
   if maintype == 'text':
        fp = open(path)
        # Note: we should handle calculating the charset
        msg = MIMEText(fp.read(), _subtype=subtype)
        fp.close()
    elif maintype == 'image':
        fp = open(path, 'rb')
        msg = MIMEImage(fp.read(), _subtype=subtype)
        fp.close()
    elif maintype == 'audio':
        fp = open(path, 'rb')
        msg = MIMEAudio(fp.read(), _subtype=subtype)
        fp.close()
    else:
        fp = open(path, 'rb')
        msg = MIMEBase(maintype, subtype)
        msg.set_payload(fp.read())
        fp.close()
        # Encode the payload using Base64
        encoders.encode_base64(msg)
```

I need exactly this kind of feature: Add any kind of file to an email.

I want to avoid this long if-elif-elif part, since it looks redundant to me.

Is there no generic way of attaching any kind of data to an email?

In my case "all kind of data" means:

- The file is only less then two mega bytes long
- The mime type can be guess by `mimetypes.guess_type()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there no generic way of attaching any kind of data to an email?

You can get rid of the first cases and only keep `MIMEBase`, which is the base (ie. generic) class for MIME types.

The first cases are only examples of what you can do if you want specific handling for some types.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I ask myself how many useless code lines in production code exists which are from this example which is from the official python docs. I guess several hundred programmers who copy+paste without thinking took the example and inserted it into their code..... Happy bloating :-)

Comment: You can also look at the code of `/usr/lib/python3.5/email/mime/application.py`, `/usr/lib/python3.5/email/mime/image.py`, etc. it's almost empty